# GStreamer won't install on mavericks

Tags: macos, plugins, gstreamer

I'm trying to install GStreamer for OSX 10.9.2. I downloaded the .pkg file, and followed all the instructions, and the installer quit with success. However, when I look in /System/Library/Frameworks, GStreamer.framework isn't there. Any tips?